# Reprogramming Pet GPS tracker to send data to my own server

Tags: gps

sorry if this is the wrong "stack". I could not find a better suited.
I bought a GPS tracker for my dog, which came with a subscription, a SIM card and a poorly developed app.
I have cancelled my subscription and want to use the device to send location info to my own server.
The device has a micro USB input and a SIM card slot. There is not much more I know, but if you have questions which may help find the answer, I can try to take it apart a little more.
So basically, is there some way I can reprogram this device to use my own SIM-card and app?
Plugging the device into my computer does nothing(as expected) <strike>however it does register in devmgmt.</strike>
Do not worry about the actual reprogramming, I can handle that myself.
Thanks in advance

Edit:
Thank you for feedback.
Image provided.
It does not, as I first thaught, register in the device manager.
I do have an IMEI number for it, but I cannot see a manufacturer anywhere on it. It might be on the underside, but the battery is glued on there.
[image: Image of device]

Comment: Is it a SIM card or a micro sd card?

Comment: Can you determine what microcontroller is being used? Is there any additional information in the devmgmt console?

Comment: It must have a model number and manufacturer somewhere on the tracker, if you could find that information it should be easy to google for the documentation on how to configure the device. Each Tracker can be configured either using configuration software or SMS commands.

Comment: It may also have an IMEI number on it somewhere . that is a 15 digit number either starting with 3 or 8. That could also help you figure out the manufacturer. Because each Manufacturer has it own Range of IMEI numbers.

Comment: @AidanHoolachan Updated post

Comment: @DawoodAwan Updated post

Comment: Are you sure it does nothing when you plug it in?  No device ID or anything?  Usually these things show up as a USB serial port.

Comment: What is the IMEI number? Is this the device? http://www.lkgpstrakcer.com/sale-8616164-remote-monitoring-assistance-gps-tracker-pet-lk120.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Model Number `LK120` After some Googling I found a documentation with the following SMS commands. [Link to documentation LK209](https://fccid.io/2AI9PLK209/User-Manual/Users-Manual-3082858)

**Note send the commands without Square Brackets**

```
// I guess you've already done 1 and 2.
1 - Set Admin Number - admin123456 [YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER]

2 - Set APN - apn123456 [APN_DETAILS]

//123456 seems to be the password - If the company you got the tracker from provided a different password - try that.
3 - SET the IP and Port Number - adminip123456 [IP_ADDRESS] [PORT_NUMBER]
```

As this Tracker is either TCP or UDP based - Can't really tell without the actual protocols and User Manual - you will have to setup a TCP and UDP Server and see which Protocol the Tracking Device connects via.

There are a few free software that can setup a TCP/UDP Server on your local machine for testing. [https://packetsender.com/]

Note that the IP address you set on the Tracker must be your Public IP Address, not Local LAN IP Address. You can get the Public IP from here - https://www.whatismyip.com/

Also you will need to open the port of your choosing on your Router and forward the Port to your PC `make sure the port is not in use by another application e.g. 9999`. This is possible for most Routers. You should be able to access your router admin panel using a browser, details should be on your router.

Also open the port on your PC firewall.

You can always check if it is possible to connect to your Server by going to CMD and running the following command (or use the Packet Sender software to test)

```
telnet [PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS] [PORT]
```

If you can connect via the above command then the tracker should also be able connect.

**Note** Let us know if the SMS commands work, you should get a response if they work.

Comment: So far so good.
I knew the SMS commands worked, just had no idea I could change the IP with sms too.
I'll keep you posted when I see a packet being recieved on my computer.
Thank you so much

Comment: Worked like a charm! I see data when listening to the port I forwarded.
Still need to figure out how to get lat. and long. from this tho, as I only see the IMEI number in Packetsender, but I'll try to find an answer myself since youve answered my question :)

Comment: @SlyTech404 if it only see the IMEI in the message it maybe an Heartbeat or Login Message - The server must respond with ACK message for the device to send the rest of the location data.